# What official material describes Baldur's Gate in 5e canon?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, forgotten-realms

Obviously, there's been an incredible amount of information published about the city of Baldur's Gate (in the Forgotten Realms setting) across the editions and various media like books, sourcebooks, video games, websites, and so on.

**What I'd like to know is the list of *official 5e* material dealing with Baldur's Gate.**

Or, to paraphrase the question, if we'd like to avoid lists:

**I'd like to know how I could and should start a new campaign based in Baldur's Gate if I wanted to keep things as close to *5e canon* as possible.**

By "official" I mean everything explicitly reviewed and approved by WotC as part of the official FR canon. (Note, please, that DM's Guild material does *not* fit the bill, unless it's explicitly approved.)

Comment: When you say *“By "official" I mean everything explicitly reviewed and approved by WotC as part of the official FR canon.”*, did you mean “as part of the official **5e** FR canon”? Normally I'd say that you obviously mean that, but since that line is your definition of what you mean, ambiguities are an issue. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only official D&D 5e tabletop products in which Baldur's Gate has appeared are:

- [*Murder in Baldur's Gate*](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/murder-baldurs-gate) - this includes a 64-page setting book on Baldur's Gate and is probably your best source.
- [*Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide*](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/sc-adventurers-guide) - About 2 pages on Baldur's Gate, definitely a summary rather than a source of detail.
- [*Hoard of the Dragon Queen*](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/hoard-dragon-queen) - Extremely brief appearance in the adventure, probably not what you're looking for.

There is also the D&D branded comic [*Legends of Baldur's Gate*](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/fiction/comicsgraphic-novels/legends-baldurs-gate), which may or may not contain useful content - if someone who has actually read it would care to edit this answer, that would be great.

Comment: I have no first hand experience (hence my asking the Q), but wasn't there an official video game dealing with the SC and possibly Baldur's Gate? Also, I remember seeing a recent-looking comics series based in BG -- is that relevant to 5e, and if so, is it canon?

Comment: There were a couple of Baldur's Gate videogames, but they were *well before* 5e.

Comment: Murder in Baldur’s Gate was published during the D&D Next phase of fifth edition, when it was still only available as a public playtest, and was also one of the earliest official sources for post-Sundering Baldur’s Gate. It also includes game rules for 3.5 and 4th edition. Can we update this answer with some idea of how official and usable the rules are with the final published version of 5E.

Comment: @GuybrushMcKenzie The rules compatibility of the adventure is entirely unimportant to the question, since it's looking for information on Baldur's Gate.

Comment: @Miniman but some rules information will interact with the city description - what kind of creatures are found where and which stat blocks to use, ability checks given for finding gear or picking locks etc. The original question asks for “official 5E material about Baldur’s Gate”, which I don’t think excludes rules information pertinent to the city? Given it’s a transitory document sitting across editions, some brief commentary on whether that information is usable would improve the answer.

Comment: You may want to update your answer to include the most recent adventure that obviously includes info about the city - *Baldur's Gate: Descent into Avernus*. (There may be passing bits of info in other adventures since the answer was posted too, but not nearly as much as in BG:DiA.)

Comment: @GuybrushMcKenzie I'd be amazed if it contained that level of detail, and I don't think the question was looking for that level of detail anyway, but regardless, I don't have access to it anyway. If you do, feel free to edit in whatever you think is pertinent. Although the other answer pretty much obviates everything in this one anyway, so it's probably not worth spending much if any effort on.

Comment: @V2Blast DigitalDevourer did a great job of that with their answer, and I'm not even slightly interested in stealing their work.

Comment: @Miniman: It might still be worth mentioning in your answer, which claims to list the "only official D&D 5e tabletop products in which Baldur's Gate has appeared" - you could simply mention it in the list, and direct readers to DigitalDevourer's answer for a fuller explanation.

Answer (score 13):

### *Baldur's Gate: Descent into Avernus*

WotC published the module [*Baldur's Gate: Descent into Avernus*](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/baldursgate_descent) on Sep. 17, 2019. I'm currently running a campaign set in it, where we're going through the module, which is why it's on my mind.

The first chapter details several areas of the city very thoroughly, and includes maps, encounters, and characters you might encounter. They also tie it into the larger world around the city, including local history and regional maps.

In the back of the book, there's a magazine-styled "gazetteer" entry that goes into much greater detail about the city. They list everything from the major houses and families, to its founding, to the running of the police and city guard. The authors outline each of the three distinct quarters of the city, as well as the smaller wards within each quarter. There's a lot of detail there, very similar in nature to the the [*Eberron: Rising from the Last War*](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/eberron) book that they released a couple of months later.

I'm not shilling for WotC or anything, but if you're interested in setting a campaign in Baldur's Gate (even if you're totally uninterested in the actual events of the module), then this book has enough detail to easily do so.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. There's no such thing as "necroposting" on Stack Exchange - Q&As are meant to stand the test of time. If answers become inaccurate over time, they should be updated accordingly (though you shouldn't totally change someone else's answer). New answers are always welcome as long as they're adding something different. That said, answers should generally independently address the question; if your answer adds to what another answer says, you may want to summarize that info in your own.